# Index/Match with IF Statement

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, formula

[image]

As you can see, I have a database table on the left. And I want to add in IF statement that allows me to lookup the [Code], [Name] and [Amount] of the top 5 of Company A ONLY. Then do a top 5 for Company B and so on. I have managed to lookup the top 5 out of ALL companies but cannot seem to add a criteria to target specific company.

Here are my formulas so far:

Formula in Column K [Company]: = `INDEX(Database,MATCH(N3,sales,0),1)`

Formula in Column L [Code]: = `INDEX(Database,MATCH(N3,sales,0),2)`

Formula in Column M [Name]: = `INDEX(Database,MATCH(N3,sales,0),2)`

Formula in Column N [Amount]: = `LARGE(sales,ROW(1:20))`

The intended result is to show the top 5 sales person in each company along with their [Code], [Name] and [Amount], feel free to suggest any edits to the worksheet.

Comment: These formulas don't work correctly! The `match` will fail if the values in `Amount` are not unique (e.g. you have 3 times `2000` in your `Amount`). You might consider using pivot tables for this job.

Comment: Are the codes unique codes? That should make it a bit easier (looks like Shawn and Chris have the same code so maybe not?).

Comment: Thought this would be simple but it's actually causing me some headaches. I can get the amounts pulling through fine from an array formula but as there are multiple matching amounts, getting the row number for index is proving troublesome. Is using a helper column an option here?

Comment: `=LARGE(IF(Company="A",Sales),ROW(1:1))` as an array formula [Ctrl+Shift+Enter] does the amount nicely, I use IF to build the `LARGE` array, i'll explain in detail when I do the answer. I am getting stumped as rows 2,3 & 4 all have the same figure for sales so I keep returning 2 for them

Comment: Yes I was thinking along the same lines. One trick I have seen to sort out ties is to add a small increment to each number in the array depending on its row number, but I don't know how to do that with a table. The other way would be to check if the code has already appeared in column L but that only works if the code is unique.

Comment: Yeah that's what I have been trying, but I use the large to produce the row numbers for small like this (Column N has the amounts from the previous large) `=SMALL(IF(Sales=N3,ROW(Sales)),1)` but this grabs row 2 continuously. `Row(1:1)` at the end only helps for the middle 3 but breaks the other 2 and I can't build an if clause to counter this.

Comment: @TomSharpe Yes, the codes should be unique. They gave me the wrong data but otherwise the assumption here is that the [Code] column is unique.

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor Is there a workaround if the amounts are matching?

Comment: A formula that can pull the top 5 highest amounts (even if they match, data will change once more data comes along) from each company would be good.

Company A top 5
Company B top 5
and so on...

Basically you'll have mini tables for each company's top 5. Once the updated data is entered, pretty sure there wont be any matching amounts.

Comment: Is automation a "must have"? Because you can archive this easily by sorting descending by amount and filter by company at the same time (using the drop downs in the headline of that table). You just need to pick out the top 5 lines then.

Comment: @Peh Yes, the point is to generate it automatically every time the data updates.

Comment: @Skinny please take a look at the answer provided. If this is acceptable and answers your question then please mark my answer as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative if you know the code is unique. After putting A into K3:K7

First get the highest amounts for Company A starting in N3

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,Database[Amount]/(Database[Company]=K3),ROWS(N$1:N1))
```

Then find the code which matches the amount, but only if it hasn't been used before (this assumes that the code is unique) starting in L3

```
=INDEX(Database[Code],MATCH(1,INDEX((Database[Company]="A")*(Database[Amount]=N3)*ISNA(MATCH(Database[Code],L$2:L2,0)),0),0))
```

Then find the matching name with a normal INDEX/MATCH starting in M3

```
=INDEX(Database[Name],MATCH(L3,Database[Code],0))
```

[image]

Comment: The last formula gives an error, for the [Name]. Noticed there was a parenthesis missing but even when I added it still gives me an error.

Comment: Never mind, had a space in the [Name] column header and it was looking like this [Name ] but either way thanks for the answer, one thing though is there a way to return the [Company] without having to manually put it in the top 5 table?

Comment: Thanks for spotting the missing paren. I should think the best way would be to make a list of all the different companies A,B,C,D etc., then have a drop-down where you could select one of them and fill in column K from there. It's perfectly do-able but I won't have chance to look at it till tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

**Okay, I have achieved this with the use of a helper column which you can hide. Please nnote though that this will only work as long as there are not more than 9 identical totals for any 1 company, I don't think you should have that issue but it may occur, the digits being added by the helper column would need to be tweaked**

[image]

***First Helper Column:***

Adds a digit to the end of the total representing the number of times that amount already exists above for that company. This formula is `=CONCATENATE([@Amount],COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A2,$D$1:D1,D2))*1`

This is multiplied by 1 to keep the number format for `LARGE`to work with.

***Second Helper Column:***

This is an array formula and will need to be input by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar.

The formula for this one is:
`=LARGE(IF(Company="A",Helper),ROW(1:1))`

What this formula does as an array formula is produce a list of results based on the `IF` statement that `LARGE` can use. Rather than the entire column being ranked largest to smallest, we can now single out the rows that have company "A" like so:

`=LARGE({20000;20001;20002;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;15000;14000;30000;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE},ROW(1:1))`

`LARGE` will only work with numeric values so the FALSES produced where column A does not match "A" will be ignored. Notice why I have used the helper column here to eliminate unique values but not affect the top 5.

`ROW(1:1)` has been used as this will automatically update when the formula is dragged down to produce the next highest result in this array.

***The main formula for top 5 array***

Again this is an Array formula so will need to be input by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar.

`=INDEX(Database,SMALL(IF(Company="A",IF(Helper=$O3,ROW(Company))),1)-1,COLUMN(A:A))`

With array formulas for some unknown reason `IF(AND())` just does not work for me so I have nested two `IF`'s instead.

Notice how I am again checking whether the first column matches "A" and then whether the last column matches the result of the second formula. What will happen is where both of these conditions match in the array (as in both produce TRUE for the same row) I wanted the row number to be returned.

`IF({TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE},IF({FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE},{2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20}))`

It looks like a mess I know, but the position where both TRUEs align gives us the row 16 as a result.

`{FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;16;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}`

As I know that there can only be one match possible for this, I use `SMALL` to grab the first smallest number to use in the `INDEX` formula for row and deduct 1 as we are not considering the headers in the INDEX formula so we actually want the 15th result.

Again, `COLUMN(A:A)` has been used for the column number to return as this will automatically update when the formula is dragged across.

**If you are struggling with my explanation and want me to provide more clarity, feel free to reach out and I will try my best to explain the logic in more detail**

Comment: Yes please if you may explain more I would appreciate it.

Comment: Could you also please explain where each formula you wrote applies in which cell.